# AVAUDIOPLAYER ViewControllers Uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avaudioplayer

Im creating an app who had 2 viewcontrollers (tab bar) and Im using AVAUDIOPlayer to play songs from urls (stocked in uitableview). The first viewcontroller listing all my url and the second View controller, the favorite that the user love.

I already searched but I can't get the right answer. I would like to control AVAUDIOPLAYER between the view controllers.

Example : The song is playing on the first one and the user select another to the second view controller. The first one stop the song and playing in the second view controller.

How can i do that? singleton avaudioplayer? appdelegate method?

THANKS

Comment: Did you need to see my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I would do is a shared instance of a global class with AVAudioPlayer in it. Something like this.

GlobalVars.h

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalVars : NSObject
{
    AVAudioPlayer *songplayer;
}

+ (GlobalVars *)sharedInstance;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *songplayer;

@end
```

GlobalsVars.m

```
#import "GlobalVars.h"

@implementation GlobalVars

@synthesize  songplayer = songplayer;

+ (GlobalVars *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static GlobalVars *instance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[GlobalVars alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
 }

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        songplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then, in your viewControllers (or in a pch file) import GlobalsVars.h and create an instance

```
GlobalVars *globals;
```

And share the instance

```
globals = [GlobalVars sharedInstance];
```

And manage your AVAudioPlayer with

```
globals.songplayer
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean now with  :

"And manage your AVAudioPlayer with"

globals.songplayer

Comment: Thank you Quetool, you solved my problem. really thank you, appreciate your support

Comment: sorry for my english! :)

Comment: with manage i mean the delegates and the functions of AVAudioPlayer: [globals.songplayer play]; [globals.songplayer pause]; set the globals.songplayer.playerItem: currentTime, duration, etc